# Transfer Drive Space from D to C in windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, memory, windows-10

I am using windows 10. My total memory is 500 Gb.

I have 50 Gb in C drive and remaining in D Drive. C Drive memory is getting full even though I have installed most of my software's in D Drive. Existing software's taking lot of memory in C drive.

How can I transfer the memory from D to C. Without taking backup at or deleting the system.

If it is not possible, how can I clean my C Drive Space.

Please refer my installed programs. Most of softwares installed in C only.
[image]

Comment: Do you have 2+ hard drives or 1 partitioned drive? Also did you mean 500GB?

Comment: There is a lot of software that is able to change the partition table e.g. Partition Magic, Acronis Disk Director. But i have not used them on Windows 10 yet. When im at Home i will try something out and post again.

Comment: Partition Magic is outdated and will srcew things up, there are many other partition tools that are current.

Comment: 500 GM = 500 Gigamegs? ;)

Comment: I had a similar issue and I used Paragon Partition Manger Community Edition to allocate some memory from my D drive to my C drive, it didn't require any backups but backups are still recommended.

Answer (score 3):

As option, if your D volume has some free space and both C and D are NTFS vols, you can shrink "D" and extend "C".

[Process is described here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)

Main idea is:

- Run build-in "Disk Managment" tool. In start menu you can find it as "Create and format hard disk partitions"
- Find your hard drive in list and select volume with free space available to shrink. [image]
- Enter how much you want to "cut" from larger volume.
  [image]
- And select your smaller "C" volume to extend. Unallocated space should be available to "stick".
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have one hard drive which is partitioned in two parts then you can reduce the size of second partition and add it to the first one (only if the two partitions are after one another and no space between them.

Most partitioning programs should be able to do it.

In this case I give you the instructions for mini partition wizard:

1. Open the mini partition wizard
2. Right click on your C drive and click extend (this will get the free space from next partition and add it to the one before in this case from D to C)
3. After that a windows will popup asks you how much space do you want to take (from the next drive)

   The maximum space that you can take depends on the amount of free space that your partition has.
4. After selecting your desired amount of space, on the top left side of the main window click apply and let it finish.

   If it asks you to restart your PC (which I don't think it will for extending) then click on restart then don't do anything. It will automatically restart your PC. In the startup it won't boot Windows, instead it will load the mini partition wizard. Let it finish and do not turn off your PC during the partitioning as it can cause data loss.

Comment: Please read http://superuser.com/editing-help. There you can learn how to correctly format numbered lists.

Comment: i will.thanks. i was going to post it as a comment but it sad i don't have enough reputation. now i don't know how i posted this comment if i don't have reputation.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer (apart from the formatting which I fixed for you) - so it didn't need to be a comment. You can always comment **on your own posts**. You only need 50 rep to be able to comment everywhere.

Comment: hey i just asked a question would you check it out.  http://superuser.com/questions/983414/elementary-os-shows-wrong-partitioning-when-installing-it

Comment: Comments are not the place to ask people to look at your questions. In fact you shouldn't ask that anywhere. People will look at your questions if they look interesting ...